# Suppress table of contents before every section in LaTeX Beamer

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, presentations

I use the LaTeX Beamer style for presentations and get a table of contents (toc) after the title page, as well as at the start of each section (where the contents of the current section are highlighted).  How can I remove all those extra tocs at the start of each section?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not the default behaviour, but you most probably have something like

```
\AtBeginSection[]{
    \begin{frame}
        \tableofcontents[currentsection]
    \end{frame}
}
```

somewhere in your code. Remove this if you don't want these `toc`'s.

Comment: Thank you.  Now that I knew what to look for, I found it in a style file, where I had searched .tex files only.